# How to get the final equation that the Random Forest algorithm uses on your independent variables to predict your dependent variable?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I am working on optimizing a manufacturing based dataset which consists of a huge number of controllable parameters. The goal is to attain the best run settings of these parameters.

I familiarized myself with several predictive algorithms while doing my research and if I say, use Random Forest to predict my dependent variable to understand how important each independent variable is, is there a way to extract the final equation/relationship the algorithm uses?

I'm not sure if my question was clear enough, please let me know if there's anything else I can add here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general way to get an interpretable equation from a random forest, explaining how your covariates affect the dependent variable. For that you can use a different model more suitable, e.g., linear regression (perhaps with kernel functions), or a decision tree. Note that you can use one model for prediction, and one model for descriptive analysis - there's no inherent reason to stick with a single model.

> use Random Forest to predict my dependent variable to understand how important each independent variable is

Understanding how important each dependent variable, does not necessarily mean you need the question in the title of your question, namely getting the actual relationship. Most random forest packages have a method quantifying how much each covariate affected the model over the train set.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of methods to estimate feature importance based on trained model. For Random Forest, most famous methods are MDI (Mean Decrease of Impurity) and MDA (Mean Decrease of Accuracy). Many popular ML libraries support feature importance estimation out of the box for Random Forest.